# Cannot use glTranslatef iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, opengl-es, exc-bad-access

When I use glTranslatef I have warning
Implicit declaration of function 'glTranslatef' is invalid in C99
If I build & run I have "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
How I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that 
you haven't imported required headers. You need following headers to be included if you want to develop OpenGL ES 1.0 application:

```
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#import <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h>
```

Don't forget to add frameworks: `OpenGLES.framework` and `QuartzCore.framework`.

**Edit:**

In OpenGL ES 2.0 you **don't** have any of the matrix operations available in 1.0 such as `glTranslatef`, `glRotatef`, `glFustrum` and many more. It's not easy to implement them by yourself but this is the price that you need to pay if you want programmable pipeline. In great short: you need to write your own functions to represent and manipulate 4x4 matrices: multiple them, multiply by vectors, create rotation, translation and scale matrices, you need also function to create projection matrix like fustrum. After that you need to declare *uniforms* in your vertex shaders to pass `projection` and `modelview` matrices. Then you need to multiply them to apply transform and projection to a vertex:

```
// Simple vertex shader
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelview;

attribute vec3 position;

void main(){
    gl_Position = projection * modelview * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

There's a great book that will teach you how to use ES1 and ES2 on iPhone - [iPhone 3d Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596804831.do). If you don't have time, stick to an ES1. It's ok if you don't need programmable pipeline. But in my opinion this is worth learning.

Comment: I do everything as you said but no success.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to use ES2? In OpenGL ES 2.0 you don't have modelview matrix operations.